# dropdown menu items with php foreach

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a dropdown menu that has items from the database using PHP for each loop The code is making only one dropdown item but the database have more than 1 rows so where is the problem?

Table:

```
-------------------------------------
| id | Address | text |
-------------------------------------
| 1  | foo     | 5    |
-------------------------------------
| 2  | bar     | 13   |
-------------------------------------
```

the dropdown contains [ foo ] only.

```
    <?php foreach($items as $newitem){?>
        <div class="dropdown-menu"  style="height:29vh; width:30vh;"aria-labelledby="myInput">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><?=$newitem['name'];?></a>
    </div>
<?}?>
```

Comment: Can you please add your `database` tag, and add your `SQL` statement as well?

Comment: Where do you define/populate `$items`?  What is the exact resulting client-side HTML from this code?

Answer (score 0):

which sql query are you using to get data from database? if you are using mysqli_fetch_array() then try mysqli_fetch_assoc().